# Xcode 13 for iOS 15 getting warning on console UICollectionViewRecursion] cv == 0x7fc7f418e000 Disabling recursion trigger logging

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, uicollectionview

I am using CompositionalLayout for UICollectionView. Before iOS 15 working fine without warning. But in Xcode 13 and iOS 15 getting  below warning while scrolling UICollectionView

```
[UICollectionViewRecursion] cv == 0x7fc7f418e000 Disabling recursion trigger logging
```

I am using diffrent type of custom cell and that custom cell using customview.

Here is my configuration for cell
UICollectionView ->CustomUICollectionviewCell->CustomUIView(load by nib)

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any real issue here. I get this message in an app that doesn't even use collection views. You should just ignore the message, which appears only in the Xcode console and probably only on a simulator.

Comment: Not only on a simulator, but I also have the same warning on my iPhone 12

Comment: I'm seeing it a lot too, but I still think my answer is right: ignore those warnings, and file a bug report with Apple if the warnings bother you.

Comment: But after getting this warming My application got crashed due to loop of updating view for Collection view what should I do?

Comment: I have [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70121104/1132951) for this too

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue on `GitHub` for `ChatLayout` which is discussing this:

https://github.com/ekazaev/ChatLayout/issues/23

And it shows is just an internal problem from Apple itself.

https://twitter.com/caughtinflux/status/1439276097464528896?s=21